# How to fix: "Failed to load module script ..." Angular 8, Electron 5

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I am trying to make an Electron 5 app using Angular 8. I've followed several tutorials online and I'm still getting the same error.

I already created a new project, ran `ng serve --open` and it worked fine, I got the default angular home page.

I then installed electron with `npm install --save-dev electron`. I created my `main.js` file in the root directory of the project and put:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win;

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })

    win.loadFile('dist/myproject/index.html')
    // Open the DevTools.
    win.webContents.openDevTools()
    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    })
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})
app.on('activate', () => {
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

I also changed the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">` in `index.html`.
I modified the `package.json` file accordingly as well:

```
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "ng build && electron ."
  },
```

The issue I'm getting when running `npm run electron` is a white screen with these errors:

```
runtime-es2015.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
styles-es2015.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
main-es2015.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
polyfills-es2015.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
vendor-es2015.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular builds in both `es5` and `es2015`, Electron might not like the indecision. Does your `tsconfig.json` have the proper target:

```
"target": "es5"
```

Comment: No, I will try this solution and see if it fixes my issue. Thank you.
EDIT: it worked