# How to solve loading module script?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I get this error:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
> non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced
> for module scripts per HTML spec. polyfills-es2015.js:1
>
> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
> non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced
> for module scripts per HTML spec.
>
> main-es2015.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded
> with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is
> enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

HTML file with scripts in the `body` section:

```html
<script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
<script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
```

Comment: Do you need to rename them to `.mjs`?

Comment: The server responds with a wrong header, the HTML posted does not really help identifying the configuration problem on the server.

Comment: I open this index.html file on the local machine  and all files was generated by Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're using Electron or not, but you should make sure your TypeScript transpilation "target" in `tsconfig.json` is set to "es5", as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57262901/4722965

Comment: Sure I use `tsconfig.json`, what changes I must do in this file

Comment: Make sure the "target" is set to "es5"

Comment: Yes, it works, but now I get error `ERROR TypeError: Constructor Map requires 'new`

Comment: You might be missing the "new" keyword when creating a new Map object somewhere in your code, e.g. var mapObj = Map(); should be var mapObj = new Map();